# Binding model dynamically in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to bind modal dynamically in Angular2. Here is my code

```
<div *ngFor="let interest of interest_data;" class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{interest.id}}">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

and the target modal element is as below

```
<div *ngFor="let interest of interest_data;">
    <div class="modal fade" id="interest.id"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Its not working . What is the proper way of doing it ?

Comment: Can you share some of you javascript code?

Comment: I have got interest_data as an array of object . So I am looping object id in both the source div and target (modal) div

Comment: what is not working? in your comment you are saying `data-target="#2"`.

Comment: When i replace value at data-target with "#2" and modal id ="2" ; its working fine . Here 2 is the value of interest.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [attr.data-target] and [attr.id].
I think you want to do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let interest of interest_data;">

  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + interest.id">
      open modal
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" [attr.id]="interest.id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        modal data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Make sure to include JQuery and bootstrap.js.

Cheers

Comment: Glad to know. :)